# Maximize area of a triangle with fixed perimeter

Tags: optimization

If perimeter of a triangle is $2d$, what is the length of sides so the triangle has maximal area?

I found some solution using circle and angles, but I think I have to use derivatives.

I need help.

Comment: If you want to use derivatives to solve it, try [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). It will be with two indeterminates, so going down that road might be difficult if you do not know how to do work with gradients. I suspect, however, that the equilateral triangle is the answer.

Comment: I tried with that formula, but I have problems to solve it. 
$T=\sqrt {s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$  and $s=\frac {a+b+c}{2}=\frac {2d}{2}=d$ and $c=2d-a-b$, I got that $T=\sqrt {d(d-a)(d-b)(a+b-d)}$. At the end, I got that $T^2=-d^4+(a+b)2d^3-(a^2+3ab+b^2)d^2+(a^2b+ab^2)d$. $\frac {\partial T^2}{\partial a}=2d^3-2d^2a-3bd^2+2abd+b^2d=0$  
$\frac {\partial T^2}{\partial b}=2d^3-3ad^2-2bd^2+a^2d+2abd=0$. If I multiply one of those equations and add to another, $2d^3$ and $2abd$ will cancel. But I don't know how to finish this and calculate $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If you set your expression for $\frac {\partial T^2}{\partial a}$ equal to zero and solve for $a$ you will get $a = \frac{2d-b}{2}$. You can then substitute that for $a$ in your original $T^2$ expression, differentiate with respect to $b$ and set that to zero.

Comment: I did it and I got $a=c=\frac{5d}{6}$, $b=\frac{d}{3}$

Comment: See also [Maximal area of a triangle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596828) and [Proving the regular n-gon maximizes area for fixed perimeter.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552961)

Answer (score 4):

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the sides of a triangle. The perimeter, $p=a+b+c$, is fixed and we want to find the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ that give the triangle maximum area. Heron's formula says that the triangle's area is
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(a-c)}$$
where s is the semiperimeter $\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\frac{p}{2}.$

Because p is fixed, we can write $c=p-a-b$. Substituting this into the equation above and squaring we find that

\begin{eqnarray}
16A^2=p(p-2a)(p-2b)(2a+2b-p). \quad\quad(1)
\end{eqnarray}

In the first part, we fix $a$ and see what we can do with $b$ to get a maximum. To this end, differentiating with respect to $b$ gives
\begin{align*}
\nonumber 32A\frac{dA}{db}=p(p-2a)\left[(p-2b)(2)+(2a+2b-p)(-2)\right]  
\nonumber =4p(p-2a)(p-2b-a).  
\end{align*}
If we set this equal to $0$ to find the critical points we find there are two possibilities. The first is that $p=2a$ which leads to $a=\frac{p}{2}$ and $b=c=\frac{p}{4},$ which do not make a proper triangle.
The more interesting possibility is that $p-2b-a=0$, or that $b=\frac{p-a}{2}.$ The significance of this value for $b$ becomes apparent when we see that $c=p-a-b=p-a-\frac{p-a}{2}=\frac{p-a}{2}=b.$ Thus we have established that the triangle is at least iscosceles.

In the second part, we use the value of $b$ just obtained, and see what we can do with $a$. Substituting for $b$ in (1) we find that
$$16A^2=p(p-2a)a^2$$
which we differentiate with respect to $a$ to get
$$32A\frac{dA}{da}=p\left[(p-2a)(2a)+a^2(-2)\right] = 2ap(p-3a).$$
Setting this equal to 0 again gives us $a=\frac{p}{3}.$
Substituting back, we find that $b = \frac{p-a}{2}=\frac{p}{3}$ and finally $c=p-a-b=\frac{p}{3}$ as well, proving that maximum area is achieved when the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: why $a=\frac{p}{2}$ and $b=c=\frac{p}{4}$ doesn't make proper triangle?

Comment: Because $a = b+c$, contravening the [Triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: If we said, after "Thus we have established that the triangle is at least iscosceles. ", simply: "By symmetry [since we could just run the same argument with $a = p - b - c$, etc], the triangle is therefore equilateral", would that be too hand-wavey?

Comment: @PeterPhipps In the last sentence, showing that c=a is unnecessary since that is covered transitively by b=a through b=c in the former paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way. Suppose that the lengths of the sides of the triangle are $a$,$b$ and $c$ such that that the perimeter of the triangle is fixed and it is $2s$. Using the Heron's formula, the area, $A$ is $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ The [AM-GM inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality)  for three positive reals $a,b,c$ states that $\displaystyle (abc)^\frac{1}{3}\leq \frac{a+b+c}{3} $wih equality at $a=b=c$.We may use it above on $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Area is $\sqrt{s (s-a) (s-b) (s-c)}$

if $s$ is $(a+b+c)/2$

since we are trying to maximize the Area, we could say we are trying to maximize the area squared so just maximize

$$s  (s-a) (s-b) (s-c)$$

since s is a constant because the perimeter is a fixed quantity, this is equivalent to maximizing $(s-a)  (s-b)  (s-c)$

but also note $(s-a) + (s-b) + (s-c) = 3s - \text{perimeter} = s$

which is a constant

so, by AM-GM where $xyz$ is the quantity, we are maximizing and $x+y+z$ is a constant $x=y=z$

so, $(s-a)=(s-b)=(s-c)$

so,  $a=b=c$

so,  the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Nice variant with no derivative.